# Desktop icons extension acts like a seperate app sometimes

Tags: gnome, 22.04, gnome-shell-extension, desktop-icons

The desktop icons extension becomes a seperate app like this:
[image]

If I select the "desktop icons app"(on the right), it displays above nautilus like this:
[image]

Then, if move to another workspace, that workspace no longer shows the desktop icons, like this:
[image]

How do I fix this or is this a bug in the OS itself?

This is on a relatively new install. It happened randomly. I have not installed any extensions of my own.